# jQuery to get elements whose id end with any of many constants

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need a jQuery to get all checked checkboxes whose ID ends with PR, PR_KD or PR_KDA. I have tried this with no luck:

```
jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1] + " input:checked").find(":[id$=_chkPR], :[id$=_chkPR_KD], :[id$=_chkPR_KDA])");
```

and also this:

```
jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1] + " input:checked:[id$=_chkPR, id$=_chkPR_KD, id$=_chkPR_KDA]")
```

I fail to use the "or" correctly. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Alejandro.

Comment: can you give any html? or jsfiddle..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example query is the closest one to a proper syntax, but you're using `$('... input:checked').find()` which will look for children of those checkboxes (of which of course there will be none).

So you need to move the `input:checked` part, or better yet `:checkbox:checked`, to exclude any radiobuttons, into your `.find`, so that you're searching within the desired container, rather than within the list of checkboxes:

```
jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1])
    .find(":checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KD], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KDA])");
```

Another way of expressing it might be:

```
jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1])
   .find('[id$=_chkPR], [id$=_chkPR_KD], [$=id_chkPR_KDA]')
   .filter(function() { return $(this).is(':checkbox:checked'); });
```

In the above code, you're finding all elements in the panel with a matching ID, and filtering out the elements, out of the matching set, that are checked checkboxes.

You could also get rid of the need of using `.find` at all, if you instead supply a *context*:

```
jQuery(":checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KD], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KDA])",
    document.getElementById(panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1]));
```

Comment: I just tryed using filter in stead of find, and it fits my needs and avoids the repetition of :checkbox:checked. Is there a drawback of using this? jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1] + " :checkbox:checked").filter(":[id$=_chkPR], :[id$=_chkPR_KD], :[id$=_chkPR_KDA]")

Comment: @Alejo: No, that's perfectly fine as well. 100 ways to do everything, in jQuery :) You don't need the `:` in the `:[id...]` selectors either...

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. Change your `find()` to this:

```
.find(":checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KD], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KDA]")
```

Final code:

```
jQuery("#" + panelInfo[0] + "_row_" + panelInfo[1]).find(":checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KD], :checkbox:checked[id$=_chkPR_KDA]")
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/9MDaV/).

Comment: -1: Your "final code" uses `.find` on all `input:checked`, which will look for *children* of the checkboxes. Your "working fiddle" uses `.find` on the container, which is correct, but completely disregards the `:checked` criteria.

Comment: @DavidHedlund, a well deserved -1. I lost my head...Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/count-checked-checkboxes